# import command does not give the expected result when executed second time

Tags: python

I have been trying to execute the below code snippet in python 3.6 IDLE by executing the below command, it works for the first time and displays the output

```
import circle

>>> import circle
Circumference of the circle:  21.99113
Area of the circle:  153.93791
>>> import circle
```

`circle.py`:

```
PI = 3.14159
r = 7
print('Circumference of the circle: ', 2 * PI * r)
print('Area of the circle: ', PI * r * r)
```

**Expected:** The output of the file should always be displayed when i import the. file

**Actual:** It works for the first time but not again.

Comment: Hi martineau, i have pasted the code of circle.py above, pasted it again below FYR: PI = 3.14159
r = 7
print('Circumference of the circle: ', 2 * PI * r)
print('Area of the circle: ', PI * r * r)

Comment: saurabh: Oh, OK...sorry, that wasn't clear when I posted my comment. `(` but it is now `;¬)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `import` a second time doesn't do what you expect. This is to prevent initialization code such as yours being executed more than once when the same module is imported from different places.

If you want to execute the initialization code in an imported module more than once, reload the module, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module).